# Cant find Youtube data v3 for channel list

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Friends,
I want to search in the query, channels that belong to a certain category (categoryId).
In the example of the app console(https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/),its ok.

But when I try to run the task with my key, the search returns no result.

i use this key:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&categoryId=GCQmVhdXR5ICYgRmFzaGlvbg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [`videoCategoryId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) parameter which filters video search results based on their [category](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories). If you specify a value for this parameter, you must also set the [**type**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) parameter's value to `video`.

You may encounter a `badRequest (400) invalidSearchFilter` error if the request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.

Note that you must set the **type** parameter to **video** if you set a value for the `eventType`, `videoCaption`, **`videoCategoryId`**, `videoDefinition`, videoDimension, videoDuration, videoEmbeddable, videoLicense, videoSyndicated, or videoType parameters.